# Php: how to lower complexity of method

Tags: php, cyclomatic-complexity

I have this method rated B on Scrutinizer (direct link: https://scrutinizer-ci.com/g/sineverba/domotic-panel/inspections/76996c9f-543f-43b4-9475-c64fe810a278/code-structure/operation/App%5CHttp%5CControllers%5CApi%5CPublicIpController%3A%3Aupdate)

```
public function update()
{
    try {
        $data = array();
        $update = false;
        $string_previous_public_ip = null;
        $current_public_ip = $this->getGateway()->fetchPublicIp($this->getIp());
        $previous_public_ip = $this->getGateway()->getLastRecord();
        $data[ 'ip_address' ] = $current_public_ip;
        if (isset($previous_public_ip->ip_address)) {
            $string_previous_public_ip = $previous_public_ip->ip_address;
            $data[ 'id' ] = $previous_public_ip->id;
        }
        if ($current_public_ip != $string_previous_public_ip) {
            $update = $this->updateOrCreate($data);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'updated' => $update
        ], 200);
    } catch (ConnectionError $e) {
        // Will return error 500
    } catch (ServiceError $e) {
        // Will return error 500
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Will return error 500
    }
    return response()->json([
        'updated' => $update
    ], 500);
}
```

Can I lower the cyclomatic complexity? I did move yet a `if/else` for the update (`updateOrCreate` method I think it is clear his work), but it is not sufficient.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the messaging from Scrutenizer in your question?

Comment: @JohnConde I did add a direct link to Scrutinizer...

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your three `catch` blocks and two `return`s do the same thing as each other.  You only need one of each.

`$update` is referenced outside of `try`, should be defined there too.

`$current_public_ip` is just another name for `$data[ 'ip_address' ]`.  It's not any shorter or clearer and doesn't resemble its other name very closely.

`$previous_public_ip` isn't an IP address, it's an object that contains an IP address and other stuff.  It would be clearer to simply name it `$previous`, which lets you drop the redundant `string_` from `$string_previous_public_ip`.  `_public` can go too.

```
public function update()
{
    $update = false;
    $status = 500; // default
    try {
        $data = array();
        $previous_ip = null;
        $data[ 'ip_address' ] = $this->getGateway()->fetchPublicIp($this->getIp());
        $previous = $this->getGateway()->getLastRecord();
        if ( isset($previous->ip_address) ) {
            $previous_ip = $previous->ip_address;
            $data[ 'id' ] = $previous->id;
        }
        if ( $data[ 'ip_address' ] != $previous_ip ) {
            $update = $this->updateOrCreate($data);
        }
        $status = 200;
    } catch ( \Exception $e ) {
        // return default status (500)
    }
    return response()->json([ 'updated' => $update ], $status);
}
```